# Parametrized Qualifiers in Dagger2

Tags: dagger-2

Let's say I have a two qualifiers: `@First` and `@Second`.

In the `Module` I'm providing two instances of `A` class - with two qualifiers:

```
@First
@Provides
static A provideFirstA(@First B b) {
    return new A(b);
}

@Second
@Provides
static A provideSecondA(@Second B b) {
    return new A(b);
}
```

As you can see, `@First` annotated `A` instance takes `@First` annotated `B` class as the dependency. The same situation with `@Second` qualifier.

Is it possible to shorten this code, remove duplication and tell Dagger: If someone needs `A` instance annotated with `@X` qualifier, create it by passing `@X` annotated `B` instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently (as of Dagger 2.16) there is no way to programmatically express a set of corresponding bindings like you describe, where `@A Foo` consumes `@A Bar` and `@A Bar` consumes `@A Baz`. Each `@Binds`, `@BindsInstance`, or `@Provides` handles exactly one binding, and Dagger doesn't associate them with one another.

If you have a long pipeline of bindings with a small set of inputs and outputs and no independent configuration, you could choose to [represent this through a subcomponent](https://google.github.io/dagger/subcomponents.html#subcomponents-for-encapsulation), where the subcomponent builder takes in your C and returns your A. This would allow you to express your pipeline once and reuse it for your `@First` through `@Fifth` bindings, in a way that approximates Guice child injectors or private modules (if you're more familiar with those).

```
@Subcomponent(modules={PipelineImplModule.class})
public interface Pipeline {
  A getA();

  @Subcomponent.Builder public interface Builder {
    @BindsInstance Builder c(C c);
    Pipeline build();
  }
}

@Module
public static class PipelineImplModule {
  @Provides
  static A provideA(B b) {
    return new A(b);
  }

  @Provides
  static B provideB(C c) {
    return new B(c);
  }
}

@Module(subcomponents={Pipeline.class})
public static class PipelineModule {
  @Provides @First
  static A provideFirstA(@First C c, Pipeline.Builder pipelineBuilder) {
    return pipelineBuilder.c(c).build().getA();
  }

  @Provides @Second
  static B provideSecondA(@Second C c, Pipeline.Builder pipelineBuilder) {
    return pipelineBuilder.c(c).build().getA();
  }
}
```